# Close a jquery dialog box on submit button

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'd like to close the following dialog box when the user clicks Add:

```
<head>
    <script>  
        $(function() {    
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog();  
        });  
    </script>
</head>
    <body> <div id="dialog" title="Select Item">  
       <%= form_tag( {:controller => :foos, :action => :update_position, :position => @i , :id => @foo.id }, :remote => true) do %>
            <td>
                <%= select_tag :position_name, options_for_select(@selection_list) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= hidden_field_tag 'position', @i %>
                <%= submit_tag "Add" , :class => "btn" %>
                <script>                
                function() {
                     $( this ).dialog( "close" );        
                }
                </script>
            </td>
        <% end %>
       </div>  
    </body>
```

I'm not sure how to arrange the statements with RoR.  Thanks for any tips.

Comment: I'd think that this question is 100% jQuery and 0% RoR.

Comment: Ok, so the solution doesn't have anything to do with the form_tag?  Are you suggesting I do the data submission without the rails coded there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the API of jqueryUI / dialog:
http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-close

Update your first script's block:

```
<script>  
    $(function() {    
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog();  
        $( "#id-of-closing-button").click(function(){
             $( "#dialog" ).dialog("close"); 
        });
    });  
</script>
```

Should work , update me if not.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not working.  Do you know what I'd replace #id-of-closing-button with in my example.  I'll mess with that a bit.

Comment: Nice, I gave my submit button an id and the matched the name with the script portion.  I'll add to your solution.  Thanks.